# Resize image without aspect ratio

Tags: android, image, image-resizing

i want to resize my bitmap image to 512px,512px. i use below code ,but when my image resized its very bad and aspect ratio affected. how i can resize my image without aspect ratio?2nd image resized with pc to 512px. 
[image]
[image]

```
public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, int newHeight, int newWidth) {
        int width = bm.getWidth();
        int height = bm.getHeight();
        float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
        float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
        Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false);
        return resizedBitmap;
    }
```

Comment: This is not Java code, it's JavaScript.  But the formula is what you're looking for:  http://dpoisn.com/demos/aspectratio.php  Check the code on that page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can resize your bitmap using this.

```
Bitmap yourBitmap;
Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(yourBitmap, newWidth, newHeight, true);
```

or:

```
resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(yourBitmap,(int)(yourBitmap.getWidth()*0.8), (int)(yourBitmap.getHeight()*0.8), true);
```